# MySQL issue with JRuby

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, jruby

When I try to run migrations, I get following error:

```
 ActiveRecord::JDBCError:
 com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: All parts
 of a PRIMARY KEY must be NOT NULL; if you need NULL in a key, use
 UNIQUE instead: CREATE TABLE `posts` (`id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
 auto_increment PRIMARY KEY, `content` text, `created_at` datetime NOT
 NULL, `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL)
 ENGINE=InnoDBarjdbc/jdbc/RubyJdbcConnection.java:587:in `execute'
```

My migration file is:

```
class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :posts do |t|
      t.text :content
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

My database.yml is:

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  username: user
  password: user

development:
  <<: *default
  database: blog_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: blog_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: blog_production
```

I have `gem 'activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter'` in my Gemfile.

When I try to run the same migration with MRI and the mysql2 gem, everything goes fine.

What should I do to fix it?

Comment: What version of rails?

Comment: Version of rails is 4.2.5

Comment: Strange, there was |a similar issue [for earlier versions of rails](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/13203). Sounds like it could be a bug in  `activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter` - I would try creating an issue on github. You can do a workaround by using `id: false` option when creating the table and then creating the `id` column manually using a SQL in a second migration. But thats a rather extreme hack for something that should just work.

Answer (score 0):

`activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter` is always chasing behind Rails ... this is fixed on **1-3-stable** branch already and should later land with gem release **1.3.20**